# Add PHP/SQL Variables into Bootbox Text Area

Tags: javascript, php, bootbox

I'm playing around with a PHP heavy social network for my friends.  I am trying to add an edit post function via a Bootbox.  Here's the code for the EDIT button:
`<button class='edit_button' id='edit$id'>Edit</button>`
And the function it calls:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {                  
      $('#edit<?php echo $id; ?>').on('click', function() {
       bootbox.prompt({
         title: "Edit your post!",
         inputType: 'textarea',
         backdrop: 'true',
         onEscape: 'true',
         callback: function (result) {
           console.log(result);
          }
        });
      });
    });
```

I tried putting `value: '<?php echo $body; ?>',` into the bootbox code, but that breaks the rest of my javascript code.

The $id in the button calls the specific post $id and that would reference the $body of the post.

How do I have the text of the $body automatically inserted into the textarea?

Comment: It may be post body contains some broken html code which causing the issue. please check post body content.

Comment: It displays perfectly in the "newsfeed" without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking in the docs of *bootbox.js* and I found this init function.

Based on your code, you can do something like this:

```
$('#edit<?php echo $id; ?>').on('click', function() {
        var prompt = bootbox.prompt({
            title: "Edit your post!",
            inputType: 'textarea',
            backdrop: 'true',
            onEscape: 'true',
            callback: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });

        prompt.init(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/path/to/file',
                type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
                dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
                data: {postID: '<?php echo $id; ?>'},
                beforeSend: function() {
                    console.log('pre loader');
                }
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                prompt.find('.bootbox-input-textarea').val('done');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                prompt.find('.bootbox-input-textarea').val('error');
            })
            .always(function(data) {
                console.log("complete");
            });
        });
    });
```

Use the init function, to perform an ajax call and load the post content inside the textarea create by *bootbox.js*, once it's loaded you can get the value edited by the *bootbox.js* callback function.

Comment: Here's my code based on above...I'm getting "error", which is coded in the ".fail" function...so, something is working but definitely NOT the output of the body.

Comment: The fail callback triggers when:
*HTTP response status 404* which means your endpoint was not found,
*HTTP response status 500* which means your endpoint contains one or more errors
or you outputted something that was not definied by your *dataType* option.